# Dynamic Arrays in Python using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
travel_mat1= numpy.array([[23,23,20,24,28,12,17,10],[11,27,17,19,24,18,23,7],
[17,26,22,13,18,29,30,18],[22,21,28,7,18,29,30,18],[27,16,33,36,10,23,26,25],
[31,13,36,14,26,23,20,27],[34,7,33,20,35,17,14,24],[28,13,27,26,37,11,10,18],
[25,17,33,28,34,10,12,15]])
```

I need to change the size of array dynamically with no loss of actual data in the array. Means, I need to have a virtual dynamic array.

The above array `Travel_mat1` is a 9X8 matrix. So if i need a 8X7 size matrix from Travel_mat1, it should look like:

```
([[23,23,20,24,28,12,17],[11,27,17,19,24,18,23],[17,26,22,13,18,29,30],
  [22,21,28,7,18,29], [27,16,33,36,10,23,26],[31,13,36,14,26,23,20],
  [34,7,33,20,35,17,14],[28,13,27,26,37,11,10]]).
```

Means, I need to reduce a row and a column in this case. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
>>> numpy.delete(numpy.delete(travel_mat1, 8, 0), 7, 1)
array([[23, 23, 20, 24, 28, 12, 17],
       [11, 27, 17, 19, 24, 18, 23],
       [17, 26, 22, 13, 18, 29, 30],
       [22, 21, 28,  7, 18, 29, 30],
       [27, 16, 33, 36, 10, 23, 26],
       [31, 13, 36, 14, 26, 23, 20],
       [34,  7, 33, 20, 35, 17, 14],
       [28, 13, 27, 26, 37, 11, 10]])
```

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan.